# How to bind GridView to the Database and perform Update/Insert operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-update, sqldatasource

I am using asp.net 4.0 C# and Sql server 2008r2.

I have found and using code from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx) to create my gridview with textboxes and from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/02/save-dynamic-textbox-values-from-gridview-to-database.aspx) to save to my database with a slight modification as seen below.

I need to recall that data from the database and populate the dynamicly created textboxes in the gridview.

I am receiveing an error "A field or property wht the name 'RowNumber' was not found on the selected data souce."  The error is on the line Gridview.DataBind(); in the Fillmygrid method.

How do I get the row to incrament for each line returned.  This column is not in the database.

My current code is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
            querytable();
        }
    }
    protected void querytable()
    {
        string id = Session["ID"] as string;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = @c1 AND column3 = 'A'", con))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", id);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.hasRows)
            {
                FillGrid();
            }
         }
      }
   }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        SetPreviousData();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }

    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
    }


    private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        string[] splitItems = null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {

            const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO SampleTable (Column1,Column2,Column3) VALUES";
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2]);
            }

        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = Session["ID"] as string;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1"); 
                string a = "A"
                sc.Add(id + "," + box1.Text + "," + a);
                rowIndex++;
                }
                InsertRecords(sc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the problem code:
Change 2 to this code:

```
    private void fillmygrid()
    {
        string id = Session["ID"] as string;
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string)
        try
        {
            string cmd "Select column2 From table where column1 = '@c1' And  column3 = 'A'";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", id);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Fetch Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            Response.Write(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

My insert statement works and I am linking to the same connection string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standardized approach, namely `SqlDataSource` bind to `GridView` control (ASP.NET). There are plenty of samples online, e.g. http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-gridview-and-sqldatasource.html This solution will allow you to SELECT, DELETE or UPDATE the Data Table in your SQL Database.

In order To ADD (i.e. INSERT) new record, use `FormView` (if necessary).
Regards,

Comment: You are welcome. That should be a good starting point for your project: you can add more functionality after you got the core data-aware controls and DB functions (CRUD) working well. Rgds,